# Informix replication

Tags: informix

We are developing our own Informix Replication handler. Informix version is 12.10. We are using Enterprise Replication, Primary-Target One-to-many option. ie... all database changes originate at the primary
database and are replicated to the target databases. We configured replication setup and replication is working fine.

Now if we write into master server, it will replicate in to slaves. The problem is we are also able to write into slaves. Is there any way to make the slaves read only? ie.. We should only be able to write into master server. Is it possible?

Please note that we are not considering Update-Anywhere Replication System, since we are using Timeseries data and there are many restrictions in informix for Conflict resolution rules for timeseries data. So please dont suggest  Update-Anywhere Replication.

Comment: Until someone with more experience in Informix Enterprise Replication posts a suggestion, maybe create the tables with one owner (user1) but use another user (user2) to do the selects/inserts/deletes/updates. Then on the slaves remove all but the select privilege from user2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the mode of the participants (slaves) to readonly.
Use this command:

```
cdr modify server --mode readonly <server_group>
```

[Refer to the Informix Enterprise Replication documentation here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.erep.doc/ids_erp_328.htm)